# Dynamic values to SQLCMD variable: Setvar

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, database-project

I am working with Visual Studio 2017 Database Project (Dacpac) and I have some SQLCMD variables in Publish file (in xml file) like below-

```
<SqlCmdVariable Include="ClientDBName">
  <Value>Client_1</Value>
</SqlCmdVariable>
```

And my problem is, we have multiple clients and we are deploying the database changes by dacpac for multiple clients in once. So if I assign the static value for my SQLCMD variable "ClientDBName" like above example, it will take the same value (same db name "Client_1") for all the clients.

And to fix that I am using PreDeployment script. In which I am trying to assign dynamic value or db name to the SQLCMD variable "CleintDBName". Like below-

```
 DECLARE @dbname varchar(50)  
 SET @dbName = "xyz"  
:setvar ClientDBName @dbName
```

But this is not working. I explored it and found this would not work. Another way I am trying to do is by assign the dbname value via calling the script like below-

```
:setvar ClientDBName "C:\GetDatabaseName.sql"
```

But this is also not working.

So can anyone help me out on this, how we can assign dynamic values to SQLCMD variable?

Comment: @DanGuzman, can you give any example?

Comment: What are you doing with that client/db name other than specifying what database to deploy to? Could you use the "generate script" option and then just push that script out to the multiple databases?

Comment: @PeterSchott, I am not aware about "generate script" option. Can you give me some more details about it.

Comment: If you're in the VS project, instead of clicking Publish, choose the Script option.  If you're using sqlpackage, there's a command line option to gen up a script instead of pushing the changes. Just remember you need to run that script in SQLCMD mode because of the variables.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage

Answer (score 1):

The sqlpackage example command below specifies SQLCMD values with the [`/Variables:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage#publish-parameters-properties-and-sqlcmd-variables) argument. These values are used instead of those in the publish profile.

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"YourDatabase.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:YourDatabaseName /TargetServerName:"." /Variables:"ClientDBName=YourValue"
```

If your actual need is the published database name, you could use the built-in `DatabaseName` SQLCMD variable instead of a user-defined SQLCMD variable, which will be the `/TargetDatabaseName` value.

Comment: but it will not work in my case because I have multiple database and for each database execution I need the value accordingly. But here we are giving one fixed value.

Comment: @sunil, couldn't you simply run sqlpackage multiple times, once for each client and a different database name?

Comment: No I can't...because this is the existing process and we are trying to change it by execute each database in a single execution only (because there are N number of database's).